# How sync Vuetify pagination UI component with an array

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

I'm trying to implement this pagination example - https://medium.com/@denny.headrick/pagination-in-vue-js-4bfce47e573b with Vuetify's Pagination UI but v-pagination expects to start on page 1.  The result set is an array so it starts at page 0.  I can't figure out how to sync them together.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is following:

```
paginatedData() {
      const start = this.pageNumber * this.size - this.size, //sets the correct start on data
        end = start + this.size;
      return this.listData.slice(start, end);
}
```

And instead of writing a different next and previous function use the @input property in the pagination.

```
<v-pagination v-model="pageNumber" :length="6" @input="nextPage" />
```

Example made out of the medium article:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-keldysh-8m0rk?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue